# Node.js/Express post request unsuccessful

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a simple CRUD app in Node.js/Express. It's an order intake form to post data to a MongoDB collection.

I cannot for the life of me see why this POST (CREATE) route is not succeeding. I’ve been troubleshooting this all morning. My other routes run just fine as validated with my console.logs.

Here is my orders route file (/routes/orders.js):

```
var express     = require("express");
var router      = express.Router();
var Order    = require("../models/order.js");

// Load Keys ===================================================================
const keys = require('../config/keys'); 


// INDEX ROUTE - show all orders
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // Get all orders from DB
    Order.find({}, function(err, allOrders){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("orders", {orders:allOrders});
        //Test to see if this returns the number of records in the collection
            console.log("There are currently " + allOrders.length + " orders."); 
        }
    });
});

// CREATE ROUTE - add new order to the DB
router.post("/", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to newOrder object
    var date = req.body.date;
    var territory = req.body.territory;
    var principal = req.body.principal;
    var customer = req.body.customer;
    var representative = req.body.representative;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var newOrder = {date: date, territory: territory, principal: principal, customer: customer, representative: representative, amount: amount};
    // Create a new order and save to DB
    Order.create(newOrder, function (err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to orders page
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log("New order created (orders route file).");
        }
    });
});


// NEW ROUTE - show form to create new customer
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render("new.ejs");
    console.log("This is coming from the order route js file.");
});
```

This is my new.ejs template file with the form:

```
<div class="container container-new py-5">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 orders-title">
            <h2>New Order</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <form action="/orders" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputDate">Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker' name="date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputTerritory">Territory</label>
                        <select id="selectTerr" class="form-control" name="territory">
                            <option>Choose a territory</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="inputPrincipal">Principal</label>
                        <select id="selectPrin" class="form-control" name="principal">
                            <option>Choose a principal</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label for="inputCustomer">Customer</label>
                        <select id="selectCust" class="form-control" name="customer">
                            <option>Choose a customer</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="inputRepresentative">Sales Rep</label>
                        <select id="selectRep" class="form-control" name="representative">
                            <option>Choose a rep</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputState">Total</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTotal" name="amount">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group new-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel btn-default btn-primary px-4">Clear</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-submit btn-default btn-primary px-4">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row row-back">
        <div class="col-lg-12 orders-title">
            <a href="/">Back to Main</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

app.js:

```
var express                 = require("express"),
    app                     = express(),
    bodyParser              = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose                = require("mongoose"),
    passport                = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy           = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose   = require("passport-local-mongoose"),
    methodOverride          = require("method-override"),
    seedDB                  = require("./seeds");

// seedDB();

// Requiring Routes ============================================================
var ordersRoutes            = require("./routes/orders"),
    indexRoutes             = require("./routes/index");

// Load Keys ===================================================================
const keys                  = require('./config/keys');    

// Map global promises
mongoose.Promise            = global.Promise;

// Mongoose Connect ============================================================

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
    useMongoClient: true
})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//==============================================================================
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use("/orders", ordersRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Something is not working? Do you see errors in console?

Comment: can you post your `server` code where you've mounted `router`

Comment: `<form action="/orders" method="POST">` feels like `action="/orders"` is the offending party, but can't know for sure if I don't know where router is mounted

Comment: @lifeisfoo - no errors...that would be nice. No behavior whatsoever. That's what has me so perplexed.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar added routes from the app.js file.

Comment: @ToddBrannon, path looks fine, have you set-up `body-parser` to parse incoming data? mount this as your first middleware to see if you're actually pointing to correct route `app.use((req, res, next) => console.log(req.url); next())`

Comment: try this `<form action="/orders/test" method="POST">` and change route to `router.post("/test", isLoggedIn, ...`. I think is the path that causes the problem

Comment: Maybe it's in the `html`? Missing button of type `submit`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Yup. It was the button type. Thanks for the fresh set of eyeballs!